# Show comment form and other info along with images in colorbox

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

What is the best way to show along with an image a comment form, comments and other image related information  with colorbox? Like in facebook's profile photos bar images?

Just opening an image node in colorbox like 'node/196?iframe=true'  is much slower than opening an image.

Answer (score 1):

the inline config parameter would be one solution

```
<style type="text/css">
    .hide-colorbox{display:none}
    #cboxLoadedContent .hide-colorbox{display:block}
</style>

$(".example8").colorbox({inline:true, href:"#inline_example1"});

<div id="inline_example1" class="hide-colorbox">
    <p><strong>This content comes from a hidden element on this page.</strong></p>
</div>
```

You can either output the required html on page load and then hide with css, or you can create the content based on the page layout.